# Why Success or Error callback function not executing properly for $http.post in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, http, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to communicate with server using following code.

```
$scope.Save = function () {
        $scope.loading = true;

        if ($scope.roleSetupModel.RoleID === "") {
            // Save
            //$scope.loading = true;
            $http.post('/SecurityModule/RoleSetup/AddRole', JSON.stringify($scope.roleSetupModel))
                .success(function (response) {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    $('#addModal').modal('hide');
                    $scope.BindDataToGrid();
                    alert("Success");
                    toastr.success(response.Message);

                })
                .error(function (response) {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    alert("Fail");
                    toastr.error(response.Message);

                });

        }
        else {
            $http.post('/SecurityModule/RoleSetup/EditRole',
                    JSON.stringify(convArrToObj($scope.roleSetupModel)))
                .success(function (response) {
                    $('#addModal').modal('hide');
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    toastr.success(response.Message);
                    $scope.BindDataToGrid();
                })
                .error(function (data) {
                    $scope.loading = false;
                    toastr.error(response.Message);
                });

        }
    }
```

But I'm getting wired behavior. The link is being hit everytime, I put a debugger there, but even before completing the request my page getting kind of refreshed making my model empty with out entering the success or error call back. I know a little about the promise object but couldn't make sense. What I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: where does `Save()` get called from? Show form html basics. Sounds like form is submitting through default process and page is reloading

Comment: <form name="name" id="name" ng-submit="Save()"></form>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is you aren't binding `$scope.Save()` to `ng-submit` of `<form>` and have it being triggered by a submit button, or you have not followed the docs for forms

If form is set up with:

```
<form name="formScopeName" ng-submit="Save()" novalidate>
```

Your `$http` should work fine. However if you have `action` set on form angular interprets that as you want to submit without ajax nd use default browser process. So make sure `action` attribute doesn't exist.

Also note there is no reason to stringify the data yourself. This will be done automatically by `$http` internally. This could be causing error perhaps

You can also pass in `$event` for extra protection and then preventDefault. Generally this isn;t necessary however.

```
ng-submit="Save($event)"
```

JS

```
$scope.Save = function (event){
    event.preventDefult();
     .....
```

Comment: Absolutely spot on. Thanks.

Comment: I removed the ng-submit from the form declaration and put ng-click to the save button which solved the problem.

Comment: but what if user submits by keyboard? Will bypass your `ng-click` and you will have same problem all over again